# Pokémon sun - locked out of 3rd island. Cannot progress forward

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

My son Left aether island before beating the first ultra beast. Is there a way to get back? The 3rd island is not unlocked yet. Is there a way to proceed with the game? I would hate for him to have to restart.

Answer (score 3):

Go back to the Aether Paradise (via the ferry terminal in either Hau'oli or Heahea) and defeat UB-01.  The game will then progress normally.